# Ajax Request not working with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm Having 2 select in my form which one will have the Main Villages and the second one has to show the small villages in depending on the main village selected.

Here is the AJAX request.

```
<script>
  $('#GN_Number').change(function()
  {
    alert('changed');
    $.get('/GN_Number/' + this.value + '/villages.json', function(villages)
    {
       var $state = $('#Village_ID');
       $state.find('option').remove().end();
       $.each(villages, function(index, village) 
       {
          $state.append('<option value="' + village.id + '">' 
                                +village.Tamil + '</option>');
       });
    });
});
```

And the HTML Code

```
<tr>
<td>
    @if($gn != null)
      <select id="GN_Number" class="selector" name="GN_Number">
        <option value=""></option>
        @foreach($gn as $n)
          <option value="{{ $n->id }}">{{ $n->Tamil }}</option>
        @endforeach
      </select>
   @endif
</td>

<td>
<select id="Village_ID" class="selector" name="Village_ID">
 </select>
 </td>
```

And the route I have for the Request is as follows

```
get('GN_Number/{code}/villages.json', function($code)
{

    return village_list::where('GN_ID', $code)->get();
});
```

While I'm testing the code in Chrome Developer mode I don't find any ajax request being made.

Please Check this code and correct me if I'm wrong

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried loggin after the success callback is made? `console.log(villages)` . My guess is that you are nit getting the response back from the called funciton.

Comment: Do you get the alert? Is the document loaded when the onchange handler is defined?

Comment: Why don't you wrap your code inside `$(document).ready`, instead of directly executing in global scope.

Comment: @RonaldPK Im not getting the alert as well